# Whether "in" instead of "by" can be used in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

1. Men and women are different by design, not intended to be rivals, but to complement each other.
2. Men are different from women by design, not  intended to be rivals,but to complement each other.

I'd like to know whether they mean the same and "in" instead of "by" can be used in this sentence.

Comment: Do you mean "by design" vs. "in design"? It would be helpful if you gave similar examples only changing the word in question.

Comment: Also, "not to intended to be rivals" is incorrect. Use "not to intend to be rivals" or "not intending to be rivals".

Comment: @user3169. It is a typo. I have deleted "to". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Men and women are different by design, not intended to be rivals, but to complement each other.
> 2. Men are different from women by design, not intended to be rivals, but to complement each other.
>
> I'd like to know whether they mean the same

Close, but the emphasis is not quite the same.  It's easier to see if you reduce the sentences down some:

1. Men and women are different [...] => *"Men and women were designed to be different from each other."*
2. Men are different from women [...] => *"Men were designed to be different from women."*

The second form specifically focuses on men's difference.  ("Men" are the subject of the sentence, not "Men and women").  It makes it sound as if women had been designed first--then men afterward as a reaction to that.  (Which is the exact opposite of what very reliable historical records tell us.  :-P)

Given these sentences in isolation, there's nothing that uses this difference in shade of meaning.  But you would be more likely to see #2 as a lead-in to descriptions of habits and characteristics of men, not really saying much about women--because they have been assumed as the "baseline" you already understand.

> and "in" instead of "by" can be used in this sentence.

The "by" in *"different by design"* makes a stronger suggestion of a designER who consciously made the design decisions.  To say things are different "in" design can just mean *"has different characteristics"*.

You would expect a statement like "Men and women are different by design" to be said by a religious creationist, relating a story from Genesis in the Bible.  "Men and women are different in design" would be something an atheist biologist would say while pointing at an anatomy chart.